# How does sorting work in AX 2012? particularly when using addsortfield()?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, ax, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I was doing a simple sort on a table column that contains names of customer's using addsortfield() in a service class. And the result was correct but a bit strange, in the list after names starting with A** there were names starting with a special character and then with number and after those came B** and C** and so on. At first this was very confusing and i doubted my own query but now that I checked it on AX client's default customer list page and matched my list with it being the exact same order as when its sorted on the client list page, I know that addsortfield() is working as its supposed to.

So my question is how has sorting been implemented by MS in AX 2012 as the order doesn't quite make sense. It should be special characters first, then number and then alphabets right?

Answer (score 3):

I just realized that sorting is working correctly and there is no weird result, the illusion of the first few rows not coming properly is because those name have a space in front them which is why they appear first in the list.